# How to implement attention for sequence to sequence model in keras. Please explain step by step

Tags: keras, seq2seq, attention-model

How to implement attention for a sequence to sequence model in keras. I understand this [seq2seq](https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-machine-translation-using-seq2seq-with-keras-c23540453c74) model, but I want to do attention with Fig B (shown in the attached link [seq2seq](https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-machine-translation-using-seq2seq-with-keras-c23540453c74)). Please explain step by step.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a tutorial site. Please do some research before asking questions here. A simple search in a search engine like Google with a query like "keras sequence to sequence attention" would lead to a couple of tutorials/articles. If you stumble upon any **programming** question/issue while reading those tutorial, then you can ask a question with specific details here and others would kindly help you.

Comment: https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html This should help you.

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/define-encoder-decoder-sequence-sequence-model-neural-machine-translation-keras/ even this is a good one.